# How to assert url was called from javascript using rspec and capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mocking, capybara, rspec-rails

### Scenario:

We use capybara integration tests to test that our frontend plumbing (javascript) is connected properly.

Sometimes all we need to validate the test is:

1. has content rendered properly on the page
2. has the js called the correct url open interaction

### Problem:

Item 1 above is easy. However, with item 2 I can't seem to find an easy way to say:

> Assert that url was called from js in browser.

### Example:

```
it "should call coorect url with correct query string" do
  visit widgets_path

  # THIS IS WHAT I NEED TO KNOW
  expect(something).to receive(:some_method).with(url: "my/test/url", params: {per_page: 2})

  # In other words, I don't want the controller action to run. I don't care about the result since the controller is being tested elsewhere.
  # I just need to know that the correct URL was called with the correct params.

  within 'ul.pagination' do
    click_on '2'
  end
end
```

I've tried mocking the controller action, but there's no way to inspect the params. Or is there? Without inspecting the params, how can I know if the correct stuff was sent? All I know it's the correct route, which isn't enough.

If I could inspect the params then this would be solved... but otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for the Rails solution, here it is! Tested with Rails 5.1.3.

1) Create a request params matcher `spec/support/matchers/request_with_params.rb`

`RSpec::Matchers.define :request_with_params do |params|
  match { |request| request.params.symbolize_keys.slice(*params.keys) == params }
end`

2) Create a helper method for your acceptance tests (you can use some logics to pass symbol instead of class UsersController -> :users if needed)

`def expect_request(controller, action, params = {})
  expect_any_instance_of(ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::Dispatcher)
    .to receive(:dispatch)
    .with(controller, action.to_s, request_with_params(params), anything)
  end
end`

3) Use it!

`expect_request(UsersController, :index)`

or with params

`expect_request(UsersController, :show, { id: 1 })`

OR

4) There is another way in using https://github.com/oesmith/puffing-billy Check this gem for intercepting requests sent by your browser. But it can be an overkill if you need to mock only certain requests to your backend app.

Answer (score 1):

Capybara integration tests intentionally don't support that. They are end-to-end blackbox tests, shouldn't generally be mocked, and really only support checking for things visible to the user in the browser. In your example case that would mean expecting on whatever visible change is caused by the JS call to the specific URL. Something like

```
expect(page).to have_css('div.widget', count: 2)
```

Comment: I do get that. But can you see from my example why I would want to do this? Mainly because I want to test all the js plumbing is correct. Js unit tests are too granular so...?

Comment: @andy No, from a feature/integration test perspective the URL that is called is irrelevant.  All that matters is that the UI is updated as expected.  When you change the number of elements per page then verify the number of elements on the page is correct.  Whether or not that was done via `/my/test/url?per_page=2` or `/blah/blah?random_name=2` doesn't matter.

Comment: I do get that. And that covers a lot of integration needs, and a lot of our tests do this. But there are some gaps. You're essentially saying "no", but I'd rather find a solution to a specific problem. In this case I need to test the js/backend plumbing. That's it, while maintaining speed with the test suite. What you describe is fine if you don't care about test suite speed ever. Know what I mean? Anyway, thanks for your time on the question.

Comment: @andy That's fine, but then you're not writing an integration test. I would also be shocked if there was any meaningful speed improvement since you still have the setup, initial page load, render, ajax request, teardown, etc - all you are really saving is the render time of the result in exchange for not really knowing that your app actually works as intended.  Seems like a bad tradeoff to me, but it's your test/app.

Comment: agreed, you’re right that it’s not an integration test. I think the issue is, what other framework of testing could I use? A js unit test would be too granular. And so I’m left in this kind of no mans land. In terms of the speed. I suspect you’re right but I wanted to find a solution so I could measure this. I hypothesise that significant gains could be made if there are enough tests because you remove a lot of capybaras automatic waits for elements to appear. If you shave off the dB io, rendering, and element wait times maybe gains could be made? Just want to measure to see.